# is there any way to view analytics data of both iOS and Android in a single dashboard?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I created iOS and Android app in the same project, however, I found the analytics data are not combined into a single dashboard view. I noticed the demo project support this functionality, how to do this?

Comment: This should happen automatically. It could be that your project hasn't been updated for this new functionality yet. If this persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. It would be helpful if you include a screenshot of what you see in the Firebase console for your project.

Comment: Thanks, Frank.  An application name always show at the right of Dashboard, you could choose only iOS application or Android application, but we cannot choose both or all.